# Correct workflow React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I am learning and practicing my react skills, and I am building a weather web app.
Now I have my app built like this:

```
-------------Header-----------
LeftSideComp       RightSideComp
```

BodyComp contains LeftSideComp and RightSideComp + the background.

LeftSideComp contains a circle with border color and the current degrees.

RightSideComp contains a few buttons to choose the date to get the weather data from.
Then it should be passed to the LeftSideComp and update the data + update the background on BodyComp.

How would I do it flow wise?
I was thinking about making a ref chain up from the RightSideComp buttons to the Body and having an event handler in there that changes the background of the body, and re-creating the LeftSideComp.

Is this the correct way of doing this? Or should I save a ref in the BodyComp to the LeftSideComp and just change the state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to handle both left & right component from your body using state, by passing theme through props to children components. so in this case, your body will be like a state manager for it's child component.

Comment: So the BodyComp state would contain both LeftSideComp and RightSideComp and the rest like I said?